# Docker volume not storing entire Data

Tags: linux, docker

I am running activeMQ in Docker and persisting data with following command . but data is not persisted in a directory completely

```
[root@kubernetes-4 activemq]# docker run -it --rm -v /MyPath:/data webcenter/activemq:5.14.3
2019-08-24 03:56:42,388 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-08-24 03:56:42,388 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/activemq.conf" during parsing
2019-08-24 03:56:42,388 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2019-08-24 03:56:42,400 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-08-24 03:56:42,400 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-08-24 03:56:42,400 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-08-24 03:56:43,403 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 16
2019-08-24 03:56:43,405 INFO spawned: 'activemq' with pid 17
2019-08-24 03:56:44,969 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-08-24 03:56:44,969 INFO success: activemq entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Data in My Path

```
cd /MyPath/
[root@kubernetes-4 MyPath]# ls
activemq
[root@kubernetes-4 MyPath]# cd activemq/
[root@kubernetes-4 activemq]# ls
[root@kubernetes-4 activemq]#
```

Data In Container

```
root@kubernetes-4 activemq]# docker exec -it 630a3fe743e2 bash
root@630a3fe743e2:/opt/activemq# ls
LICENSE  README.txt               bin   conf.tmp  docs      lib  webapps
NOTICE   activemq-all-5.14.3.jar  conf  data      examples  tmp  webapps-demo
root@630a3fe743e2:/opt/activemq# cd data
root@630a3fe743e2:/opt/activemq/data# ls
activemq.log
root@630a3fe743e2:/opt/activemq/data# cd ..
root@630a3fe743e2:/opt/activemq# cd /data/
root@630a3fe743e2:/data# ls
activemq
root@630a3fe743e2:/data# cd activemq/
root@630a3fe743e2:/data/activemq# ls
activemq.pid  kahadb  localhost
root@630a3fe743e2:/data/activemq#
```

Comment: Hi @max, welcome to the club) Would you please explain your issue a bit more detailed

Comment: @Yasen, Thanks , let me explain in a bit details
I have a docker container webcenter/activemq:5.14.3 which creates some data in /data directory which i want to persist even if container is destroyed
I want it to persist the data at /MyPath so i used command -v /MyPath:/data while running container
after running i checked MyPath and I could only see parent folder and I checked inside the container i could see many files which are not stored on my host directory
this is the dockerfile
https://github.com/disaster37/activemq/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount the exact [activemq direcotry](https://hub.docker.com/r/webcenter/activemq/) and you will see everything working fine.

```
docker run -dit --rm -v /MyPath:/data/activemq webcenter/activemq:5.14.3
```

Second thing, you are not mounting `/opt/activemq/data` so will not be accessible on the host.

For logs purpose, you can mount `v /var/log/activemq:/var/log/activemq`

Comment: Thanks Adiii, Can you please explain why is this behaviour?
What I can do to persist everything present in /data?

Comment: This is the correct answer but the help page mentioned on Docker hub is wrong still. There is a typo in the way they mount the volumes. You can see the correct version on Github: `https://github.com/disaster37/activemq/blob/master/README.md`. The master branch is correct while the develop branch has the error still.

Comment: @Mihai perfect thanks for sharing. max can look into it https://github.com/disaster37/activemq/blob/master/README.md they should update the documentation.